# Dropdown menu hidden outside header element

Tags: html, css, overflow

I've been trying to add a dropdown menu to the header nav in a website, but the dropdown will simply not be visible outside the header element.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1ew293gr/) showing the problem. I've tried setting overflow to visible, but that hasn't worked so far. I'd really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction

Code:

```css
header {
background-color: white;
width: 100%;
overflow: visible;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
header:after {
content: "";
display: table;
clear: both;
}
header .oc {
height: 105px;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
}
.oc {
max-width: 1300px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
padding: 0 10px;
}
.oc:after {
content: "";
display: table;
clear: both;
}
header .nav-logo {
display: block;
left: 10px;
height: 54px;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
-moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
-o-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
}
header .nav-logo {
display: block;
left: 10px;
height: 54px;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
-moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
-o-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
}
header .main-nav {
right: 10px;
position: absolute;
top: 40%;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-40%);
-moz-transform: translateY(-40%);
-ms-transform: translateY(-40%);
-o-transform: translateY(-40%);
transform: translateY(-40%);
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
-webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
}
header .main-nav ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-table;
}
header .main-nav ul li {
display: inline-block;
}
header .main-nav-item {
color: #666668;
font-weight: 200;
font-size: 21px;
margin-left: 25px;
padding: 0 0 4px 0;
position: relative;
outline: none;
transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
header .main-nav-item:after {
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 2px;
background: #89a959;
content: "";
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.3s, -moz-transform 0.3s;
transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
-webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
-moz-transform: translateY(10px);
transform: translateY(10px);
}
header .main-nav ul ul {
display: none;
background: #fff;
border-top: 2px solid #73973f;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 150%;
z-index: 10000;
transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
header .main-nav ul ul li {
display: block;
position: relative;
padding: 15px;
transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
header .main-nav ul ul li a {
color: #666;
}
header .main-nav ul ul li:hover {
background: #eee;
}
header .main-nav ul li:hover > ul {
display: block;
}
.pitch {
background-color: #f6faf0;
padding: 40px 0;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
-webkit-transition: height 1.5s ease-in-out, padding 0.5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: height 1.5s ease-in-out, padding 0.5s ease-in-out;
transition: height 1.5s ease-in-out, padding 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.pitch:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
bottom: -25px;
z-index: 2;
height: 0;
width: 0;
border-left: 25px solid transparent;
border-right: 25px solid transparent;
border-top: 25px solid #f6faee;
}
```

```html
 <header>
  <div class="oc">
   <a href="/" class="nav-logo">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x50"
   </a>
   <nav class="main-nav">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#" class="main-nav-item" data-hover="About">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="main-nav-item" data-hover="Plans">Plans</a></li>
     <li>
      <a href="#" class="main-nav-item" data-hover="Contact">Contact</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-item">Request a Demo</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-item">Talk To Us</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#" class="main-nav-item" data-hover="Request a Demo">Request a Demo</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="main-nav-item" data-hover="API">API</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="main-nav-item-login" data-hover="Login">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav> 
  </div>
 </header>
 <div class="pitch">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut nec condimentum elit. Cras eget fringilla velit, id pulvinar libero. Sed venenatis, orci eu aliquet lacinia, orci eros pharetra erat, ac bibendum ex purus rhoncus erat. Sed pharetra in orci sed sollicitudin. Aliquam fringilla mollis arcu, aliquam euismod urna commodo nec. Nunc ut lorem augue. Phasellus quis nibh pretium, ultricies mauris et, tincidunt nisi. Suspendisse fermentum, libero eu pulvinar semper, massa ante tincidunt nisi, sed aliquet elit justo a purus.</p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a z-index issue. Your header dropdown menu is being "hidden" behind the `.pitch` content. So I updated your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pck4kxfa/).

Just add `position:relative;z-index:2;` to `.header` and `position: relative;z-index:1;` to `.pitch`. Then your dropdown will overlay `.pitch`.